# EF core auto increment int value for a composite key

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my .NET Core project I got this class that represent a table in the DB that has a key composed by three fields:

```
public class Turn
{
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("playerHost")]
    public string ownerId { get; set; }

    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("match")]
    public Guid matchId { get; set; }
    [Column(Order = 3)] 
    public int counterKey { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have the `counterKey` as an autoincrement but it has to increment according to the values of `matchId` and `ownerId`. So for every pair of <`matchId`, `ownerId`> there will be a counter that increment for every new entry. How can I do this in EF Core?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you certain you really need this? Whether it is an independently incrementing key or incrementing only within the two other keys, in both cases it represents a unique key. I ask because it's far easier to just have an independently incrementing key.

Comment: For every match i got the turn 0, turn 1 etc.. and there is the turn 0 for player 1 and the turn 0 for player 2. Manage this in automatic could be for sure a good way to avoid bugs.